# Make Python Pandas Faster

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, dask

I have the code below, which works successfully, and is used to parse, clean log files (very large in size) and output into smaller sized files. This would take about 12-14 mins to process 1 GB worth of logs (on my laptop). Can this be made faster? Could Dask or parallelism or asyncio or another help speed this up?

I am new to python and pandas, and I have googled around, but am totally confused and cant seem to adopt any of the examples I saw.

**Pls help improve this code**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        try:
            for df in pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, engine='python', quoting=3, chunksize=1200000):
                df = df[0].str.strip(' \t"').str.split('[,|;: \t]+', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: 'data'}) 

                mask = (df.email.str.contains(emailreg, regex=True, na=False)) & (~df.data.str.contains(asciireg, regex=True, na=False))
                df2 = df[~mask].copy()
                df = df[mask].copy()
                df2[['email', 'data']].to_csv("errorfile", sep=':', index=False, header=False, mode='a', compression='gzip')
                del df2
                del mask

                for x in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789":
                    df2 = df[df.email.str.startswith(x)]
                    if (df.email.size > 0):
                        df2[['email', 'data']].to_csv(x, sep=':', index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

**Sample log file**

```
"email1@foo.com:datahere2     
email2@foo.com:datahere2
email3@foo.com datahere2
email5@foo.com;dtat'ah'ere2 
wrongemailfoo.com
email3@foo.com:datahere2
```

Comment: share a couple of rows of your original data, as well as your expected output. Also ,state what you are trying to achieve; someone might be able to answer your question. Also, run a profiler on your code, to find out where the bottleneck is

Comment: The for-loops are excellent candidates for parallelisation, but there are quite a few inefficiencies in the code - I would look at those first. For example: (1) Do you really need the copies of the dataframes? (2) Do you really need pandas? (3) Does the code run faster if you combine emailreg and asciireg into a single regex? (4) If that is an option, disabling or reducing logging should save quite some time. If you create a test-set of reasonable size you can make changes to the code and measure if it  executes faster.

Comment: Thanks Louic. can you pls help with the code? I am still a newbie coder

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular it looks to me that on the snippet you shared `except` is missing. If each df fit in RAM/cores you can easily parallelize your code with `dask` or `multiprocessing`.